# OnClickListener() doesn't allow me to start the program

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, onclicklistener

this is oncreate function im calling Appdata() inside this method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    conpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    AddData();
}

public  void AddData() {
    register.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                            boolean isInserted = db.insertData(email.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString(), conpass.getText().toString());
                          if(isInserted == true)
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );

}
```

In Appdata function [OnClickListener()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd14K.png) is created but my problem is when i run this program app become stop and restart
when i hide inside code of Appdata() program ,its run without any error
i uploaded image [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd14K.png)

Comment: Post error message that you see on the Android Monitor

Comment: no ...it only showing "app keeps stopping " in emulator

Comment: You don't see crash dump on the Android Monitor?

Comment: no..i tried to put onclicklistener inside OnCreate() but it doesnt work

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml

Comment: When does app crash? As soon as you launch the activity or after you click on the button?

Comment: as soon as launch

Comment: [IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/ftfo03.png[/IMG] see activity_main.xml      http://i64.tinypic.com/2qalg2f.jpg dataabsehelper class im calling this class under appdata()

Comment: Where is the edit texts and buttons in your layout file?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/ncdona/9
http://tinypic.com/r/a0jnn9/9
http://tinypic.com/r/qzjfpj/9

Comment: Is it in the activity_main.xml?

Comment: noo its in another

Comment: Put that in the activity_main.xml file.

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no button exists with the id R.id.btn_register in your xml file this is causes NullPointerException when you tried to set up the click listener. Add the buttons and EditTexts in your xml layout and you're good to go.

Add the below code in your activity_main.xml

```
<include
     layout= "@layout/your_extra_layout_file"/>
```

You can use android:onclick="function_name" attribute with the button 
And implement the function in the activity like below.

```
public void function_name(View view) {
     //do the action here
}
```

Comment: it works... but suppose ,i want to code(onclicklistener()) in my_extra_layout how to do that ?

Comment: http://i64.tinypic.com/eqo8pj.png this happen another deisng overload to activity_main

Comment: i put my AddData() in my_extra_layout but problem is occured when i clicked in register (button)